# MySQL Change a column ENUM value

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a MySQL table "`content`" which has a column `page_type` of type `ENUM`. The `ENUM` values are `NEWS` & `PRESS_RELEASE`.  I need to replace `NEWS` with `FEATURED_COVERAGE`:

```
ALTER TABLE `content` CHANGE `pagetype` `pagetype` ENUM('FEATURED_COVERAGE','PRESS_RELEASE') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

But now the records in the table, which earlier had page_type `NEWS` are now empty, and there is no way that I can identify which records are `NEWS`, so that I can rename those to `FEATURED_COVERAGE`.

How to resolve such issues?

Comment: What u want? rename a existing enum value to new enum value or add a new enum value? Not clear in you question.

Comment: rename an existing enum value.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to rename the existing enum value `NEWS` to `FEATURED_COVERAGE`. If so, you need to follow below steps,

1. Alter the table and add the new enum value to the column, so that you will have 3 enums

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `content` CHANGE `pagetype` `pagetype`
   ENUM('FEATURED_COVERAGE','PRESS_RELEASE', 'NEWS') CHARACTER SET utf8
   COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
   ```
2. Set the old enum value to new value for all records.

   ```
   UPDATE `content` set `pagetype` = 'FEATURED_COVERAGE' where
   `pagetype` = 'NEWS';
   ```
3. Alter the table and drop the old enum value.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `content` CHANGE `pagetype` `pagetype`
   ENUM('FEATURED_COVERAGE','PRESS_RELEASE') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
   utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
   ```

Answer (score 8):

MySQL's enum always has a hidden option which is 0 as integer and '' as string. When you try to assign an invalid value it uses the hidden one.

Assuming all your empty values were 'NEWS' before the update you can change them with

```
UPDATE content SET pagetype = 'FEATURED_COVERAGE' WHERE pagetype = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think default might have helped.

```
ALTER TABLE `content`
CHANGE `pagetype` `pagetype` ENUM('FEATURED_COVERAGE','PRESS_RELEASE') 
   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULt 'FEATURED_COVERAGE';
```

Now you have to blindly to an update

And never use an enum column if your value set is changing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have changed only one enum it will not be difficult for you

Try using this

```
UPDATE content SET pagetype = 'FEATURED_COVERAGE' WHERE pagetype = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE name_table
CHANGE name_column name_column enum ('make','value', 'enum','again');
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes / queries. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the codes / queries will fix the problem that was described in the question.