# Is there a way to remove a value from an enum in MySQL/MariaDB without locking the table?

Tags: mysql, enums, mariadb

Let's say I have a MySQL column:

```
color: ENUM('red', 'blue', 'green')
```

I want to remove "blue" from the enum. As far as I know, this is the only way to do it, since [it doesn't merely add values at the end](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#:%7E:text=an%20expensive%20operation.-,Modifying%20the%20definition%20of%20an%20ENUM%20or%20SET%20column,-CREATE%20TABLE%20t1)

```sql
ALTER TABLE `UserNotifications` CHANGE `color` `color` ENUM('red', 'green', 'blue') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, ALGORITHM=COPY, LOCK=SHARED;
```

This locks the entire table from writes. for the duration of the copy.

Right now, I believe the only solutions I have are:

1. Create a new column and copying over the data, which can be batched and use online DML [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642695/mysql-change-a-column-enum-value)
2. Using a tool like [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html)

Are there any other options I'm missing?

Comment: One reason not to use ENUM. Consider a CHECK constraint.

Comment: *I want to remove "blue" from the enum.* What a problem? remove this value from the rows then alter the column definition.

Comment: *As far as I know, this is the only way to do it, since it doesn't merely add values at the end* ??? You have not understood the article, it seems. It tells explicitly that "Modifying the definition of an ENUM or SET column" is in-place operation.

Comment: If the changing of the enum results in a change in the numbering of the values, then the operation requires table copy.

Comment: The [mariadb docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations-with-the-inplace-alter-algorithm/#adding-a-new-enum-option) don't list removing a enum element as an online operation. Further to what @Shadow said, the rows store the enum value as an ordinal value with the enum, removing a non-end "blue" would need to renumber the "green" rows.

Comment: I've used pt-online-schema-change. This eliminates the pain of most types of ALTER TABLE changes. At my last company we used this to run tens of thousands of alters in production during peak hours without issue. Is it a problem for you to use it?

Comment: [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) is another free online schema change tool. So that's another option.